# Cannot run pip in window python 2.7.14

Tags: python-2.7, pywinauto

when I am at C:\Python27\python.exe

When I key in: 'cd\' and it appeared: '...'. I key in 'cd python2.7' and it appeared: 'Syntax Error: invalid syntax'.

so I try again.

I key in: 'cd\' and key in: 'python -m pip install -U pip'. It appeared : 'Syntax Error: invalid syntax'.

How should I solve it?

Comment: It is amazing what level of cognitive skills you are expecting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip command is not a Python syntax :)
It’s an executable file. To run it from Python you have to use subprocess module. But for single run see below.

Just run it in cmd.exe console (press Ctrl+R, type cmd.exe, press Enter), not in python.exe:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
pip install -U pywinauto
```

or with full path (if you have few Pythons installed):

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe install -U pywinauto
```

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem

Comment: If it helped, please mark the answer as accepted (grayed check box at the left side should work).